# Чередование букв в именах

Tags: словообразование, ономастика

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем вызвано чередование букв в именах в таких близких языках, как русский и украинский? Например: Николай - Микола, Елена - Олена, Филипп - Пилип и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все эти имена пришли в славянские языки с запада, например из Греции и Рима. А их изменение  было, скорее всего, предназначено для их, скажем, славянизации.